# How to add a Satellite / Terrain Base-Map to a QGIS Project

Tags: qgis, google-maps, basemap, bing-maps, xyz-tiles

When doing a project in QGIS it is very hard to find a satellite images suiting to be used as the **BASE MAP** of my project. Therefore, I would like to have a **Google or Bing or Esri** like **BASE MAP** as the Base Map of my project

Therefor please explain,

How to add a **Satellite or Terrain or Satellite/Terrain Street Hybrid Base Map** to my QGIS project which will be **Automatically Updating**.